# How can I unregister events subscribed via Ext.js 4.1.3 Controller's control() method?

Tags: extjs, model-view-controller, observer-pattern

The `addListener()` method (present in `Component`, `Observer`, etc.) has its opposite `removeListener()`. How can I unregister events subscribed via `Controller`'s `control()` method in Ext.js 4.1.3?

As [suggested](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?279586-How-can-I-unregister-envents-subscribed-via-Controller-s-control%28%29-method) by [@scottmartin](http://www.sencha.com/forum/member.php?165873-scottmartin) (Sencha support), I could try this in Ext 4.2.2:

```
//remove controller listeners using private method
Ext.app.EventBus.unlisten(myController.id);
```

However, in Ext 4.1.3, this method and its internal referenced class `Ext.app.EventDomain` aren't available.

Comment: Your question helped me to find solution for ExtJs 4.2. If you have found solution for 4.1.x, you should post it as well, as it will be really helpful for others.

Comment: I don't have the solution. I believe I solved my original problem through a different path.